# Matching Multiple Columns Excel

Tags: excel, match, vlookup, formulas

I would like to match 3 columns in a different sheet in excel and if all match then return a result. The data needs to search for the results (i.e not specific rows)

Example:

Sheet1

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G
11  22  33  44  55  66  (Blank)
22  11  33  55  44  66  (Blank)
```

Sheet2

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G
22  11  33  55  44  66  Yes
11  22  33  44  55  66  Yes
33  44  55  66  11  22  No
11  22  33  44  55  66  No
22  11  33  55  44  66  No
```

If Column C, D (both) matches C and D in Sheet2 AND G is yes then display yes in Sheet1, otherwise no
It cannot be a partial match, both columns C and D need to match and G be yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Excell, you can use functions.
For example : IF( condition, [value_if_true], [value_if_false] )

into a empty cell (where you want to write the result) you can write

```
=IF(AND( sheet1.C1=sheet2.C1, Sheet1.D1=Sheet2.D2, Sheet2.G1="yes"), "yes", "NO MATCH" )
```

Comment: The data can be random, i think i need to index it first. how would i do that

Answer (score 0):

sheet1.C11 --> gives you C11 for sheet 1

sheet2.C11 --> gives you C11 for sheet 2

after you can match their value as you want :-D